# VUE: make changes in parent if child emits event

Tags: events, vuejs2, vue-component, emit

Having the following vue structure:

```
<!-- Parent Component -->
    <div v-for="item in items">
       <h1>{{item.title}}</h1>
        <!-- this is my target button --> 
       <button></button>
       <child :parentid="item.id"/>
    </div>

<!-- Child Component-->
    <div v-for="subitem in subitems">
      <h2>{{subitem.title}}</h2>
       <button v-on:click="delete(subitem.id)" v-on:update-parent-button="howToDo()" >delete</button>
    </div>
```

I want to emit an event to parent to disable parent button if `subitems` length is 0. Subitems in child component are getting refreshed on each delete and I watch for this state mutation like this:

```
watch: {
     subitems(newValue, oldValue) {
                this.$emit('update-parent-button', ('test', newValue.length))
            }
        },
```

How can I do this with not too much effort to target the right parent element

Comment: Doesn't the parent component also has access to the subitems in the child component? Where is the child component getting the subitems from? If that's the case, you don't even need to rely on watchers and event listeners, but just a simple computed property.

Comment: child components fetches data subitems in function of passed prop `:parentid`. the ajax request is inside child component for the subitems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, an example that I believe does what you're requesting:

```js
const Child = {
  template: `
    <div>
      <div v-for="subitem in subitems">
        <h2>{{ subitem.title }}</h2>
        <button @click="deleteItem(subitem.id)">delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  
  props: ['parentid'],
  
  data () {
    return {
      subitems: [
        { title: 'Subitem a', id: 6 },
        { title: 'Subitem b', id: 7 }
      ]
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    deleteItem (id) {
      this.subitems = this.subitems.filter(item => item.id !== id)
    }
  },
  
  watch: {
    'subitems.length': {
      immediate: true,
      
      handler (newLength) {
        this.$emit('update-subitem-count', {
          id: this.parentid,
          count: newLength
        })
      }
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  components: {
    Child
  },
  
  data () {
    return {
      hasSubitems: {},
      items: [
        { title: 'Item A', id: 1 },
        { title: 'Item B', id: 2 },
        { title: 'Item C', id: 3 }
      ]
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    onSubitemChange ({ count, id }) {
      this.$set(this.hasSubitems, id, count > 0)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in items">
    <h1>{{ item.title }}</h1>
    <button :disabled="!hasSubitems[item.id]">Target button</button>
    <child
      :parentid="item.id"
      @update-subitem-count="onSubitemChange"
    ></child>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to keep the structure similar to the code in the question.

Notes:

1. I've added an object called `hasSubitems` to the parent component. This is used as a map from the item ids to a boolean value that determines whether that button should be enabled. There are many other ways this could be done. Instead, the boolean could be stored as a property of the `item`. Alternatively, a new component could be introduced to hold the contents of the `v-for` and that component could hold the relevant state. Generally, if you have a non-trivial `v-for` it's worthwhile considering introducing a new component and just looping over that instead.
2. I've changed the `watch` to `subitems.length` instead of `subitems`. This isn't required but it seemed more targeted to the quantity we actually care about.
3. I've included the `parentid` in the emitted event. This also isn't needed but it makes it slightly easier to write the listener code in the parent component. Otherwise we would have to grab that id from the `v-for` `item` within the listener attribute.
4. The original code has a strange bracketed expression `('test', newValue.length)`. Not sure what that was trying to achieve but I doubt it was doing what you were hoping for.
5. I've used `immediate` on the `watch` so that it will fire straightaway, ensuring the button is initially in the correct state. That might not be relevant if you are loading the initial list asynchronously anyway.
6. I've used `$set` to update `hasSubitems`. This is required because new properties are being added to the object and Vue cannot detect those otherwise. An alternative would be to ensure that `hasSubitems` is correctly populated with all the properties when it is first created. That may be possible depending on where `items` come from.

Beyond all that, I would note that using events in this way screams misuse and suggests that there's a more fundamental flaw in your design. It's difficult to say from the information provided what that might be. However, I will have a stab at making a suggestion.

As I noted earlier, whenever you have a non-trivial `v-for` it is worth considering introducing a new component. So you may want to consider changing the parent component template to something like this:

```html
<my-item-component
  v-for="item in items"
  :item="item"
/>
```

You'd then introduce a component called `my-item-component`. This component would wrap the `<h1>`, `<button>` and `<child>` components. As I noted earlier, such a component could hold the state for whether the `<button>` should be disabled. Such state could be held in a simple boolean property. But beyond that, it might make more sense for `my-item-component` to take on the responsibility for loading and manipulating the subitems.

It may also be possible to solve your problems using slots instead. When data seems to be flowing the wrong way that can be a hint that you need a slot, or more specifically a scoped slot.

Figuring out exactly which responsibilities should lie where can be tricky and there's nowhere near enough information in the question to be sure what the best way is in your scenario. However, strange use of events to communicate between components does typically suggest that you've divided up your concerns in slightly the wrong way and responsibilities may need shifting around.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detaliated answer it helped me a lot to get a better undersatnding about vue parent-child components